# JQuery: Change image on page based on class in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress page where I want to display a featured image on the header of the homepage, but no other pages. I set up a script to read whether the body tag contains the "home" class and display an image based on that. The code looks like this:

```
<script>
    if($('body').hasClass("home")) {
    $('#headshot').html('<img src="http://www.kieferslaton.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Headshot1.png" alt="headshot">');
}
</script>
```

What's wrong with this script?

Comment: Yes, what's wrong? Any error you encountered?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a `$ is not defined` in the console, wordpress is in no-conflict mode by default ?

Comment: And this looks like something you could do with CSS -> `body.home #headshot img {display:inline}`

Comment: or even better, in PHP `<?php if ( is_home() ) echo $img; ?>`

Comment: adding the line for document ready worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code into function fired on DOM ready:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if($('body').hasClass("home")) {
            $('#headshot').html('<img src="http://www.kieferslaton.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Headshot1.png" alt="headshot">');
        }
    });
</script>
```

[More info](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery needs to know when to start the function. Start it after the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('body').hasClass("home")) {
    $('#headshot').html('<img src="http://www.kieferslaton.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Headshot1.png" alt="headshot">');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include jQuery library in your header section? Also some times $ symbol may conflict in wordpress, write full jQuery term when initialize jQuery this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 if($('body').hasClass("home")) {
 $('#headshot').html('<img src="http://www.kieferslaton.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Headshot1.png" alt="headshot">');
 }
});
```